# How to use CSS Seletor to capture a specific attribute in element

Tags: css-selectors

How to use CSS Seletor to capture  attribute?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You should show what you have tried, what is not working with your approach. SO is not a "write and give me the code" service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `a[data-video-source] {  }`

You can also select elements with a specific value to the attribute. 
More here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp